# Can anyone help me for this first degree floor function equation?

Tags: functions

Find $y$ such that

$$\lfloor y \rfloor + \lfloor 3y \rfloor = 5$$

First, I use the properties that $$n \leq y <n+1$$
And suppose

$$\lfloor y\rfloor = 5-n$$

and

$$\lfloor 3y\rfloor = n$$

But I’m stuck, could anyone help me?

Comment: Do you just need one example of such a $y$ (in which case you could just try some reasonable guesses until you find one), or do you want a description of all the solutions $y$ (which is also easy, but better done by thinking than by trial and error).

Comment: @HavanaTime Please do not vandalize the post after you have received an answer. Doing so can get you into trouble on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write y as $n+d$ .Now the first term turns out to be n and for second term take cases for $0<d<1/3$ ,$1/3<=d<2/3$ and $2/3<=d<1$. Can you do after that ?

Comment: answer should be $(4/3,5/3)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $1$ is too small and $2$ is too big.  So any values of $y$ will have to be between $1$ and $2$.

For $y$ between $1$ and $2$, $\lfloor y \rfloor = 1$.

So you just have to pick values that get the $\lfloor 3y \rfloor$ term to come out right.